# 301 subdomains to root domain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, http-status-code-301

I recently rebuilt a website that originally had a structure of 2 subdomain (1 for each language)
Now I want to 301 all the URLs from these old/deleted subdomains to the root domain.

I don't want to 301 all of the URLs to the root domain, instead I need to 301 specific URLs from the old subdomains to the new URLs on the root domain like this:

en.mydomain.com/about-us/ 301 to
mydomain.com/about-us/

es.mydomain.com/about-us/ 301 to
mydomain.com/about-us/

In total it might be ~30 URLs for each subdomain and I need to manually 301 them to their new URLs on the root domain

Do I need to recreate the old subdomains? Or can this be achieved via the root domain?

I also need to use some wildcard for www, non-www, http, https for ALL URLs.

Comment: Depends on which is the default host for your domain. If that is your "root domain" (as you called it), then that is where you can implement the redirection rules using the `RewriteCond` directive to find out which host name ("subdomain") has actually been requested.

Comment: I have changed host. The old subdomains were hosted on a different webhost.
My newly built site which only use the root domain, mydomain.com is hosted on a new webhost.

Comment: I did not refer to your hosting, but to the default host. A http server configures "hosts", something you called "domain" or "subdomain". Those are actually http hosts. Typically one of those hosts serves as the "default host". That is the one configuration that is chosen by the http server to respond to requests requesting a host to which no matching host configuration can be found. So if you do _not_ have any hosts defined for those "subdomains", then those requests will get answered by that default host. That is where you want to implement the redirection rules.

Comment: It might make sense for you to start reading a bit about that topic. You want to learn about "virtual hosts", "mass virtual hosting", "host aliases" and especially the features the apache rewriting module offers. I suggest you start digging into the documentation. As typical for OpenSource software it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/

Comment: I'm thankful for your time and answer but now I just got confused of everything.

I thought I made myself pretty clear in my topic that I want to 301 my 2 subdomains to my "default host" or whatever it's called.

Should I re-create my old subdomains and add a .htaccess in both of these, or can I add a .htaccess in my "default host"?

I have done many 301 before, but that has always been using some 301 plugin for wordpress and always within 1 single domain, not like this time with subdomains

Comment: You can add those rules in your default host, if your http server has such a default host. You just need to take care that those rules only get applied, to requests to a specific host ("subdomain") and not to all requests to that default host. That is what you need the `RewriteCond` for.

Comment: I posted an example for such rule as answer below...

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments to the question you can implement such redirection rules inside the default host configured in your http server, since that host will respond to requests to undefined host.

You need something like that probably:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www)?\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?about-us/?$ /about-us/ [R=301]
```

In general you should prefer to implement such rules in the actual host configuration. If you have no access to that (read: cheap hosting provider), then you can also use a distributed configuration file (often called ".htaccess"), but that comes with a few penalties.

It is also possible to hand over the requested language if desired:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www)?\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?about-us/?$ /about-us/?lang=%1 [R=301]
```

It probably makes sense to start with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as expected. That prevents nasty caching issues on the way...